# Closure Compiler: Preserve function argument names?

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler, iife

I was wondering if there is a way to preserve function argument names.

Example:

```
(function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p) {
... 

})(...);
```

We are looking for a way to optimize compression of IIFE based modules. If Closure Compiler could be configured to preserve argument names it would be a solution to remove the argument related data for each module.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to prevent function argument renaming without creating a custom build of the compiler.